# How (in matlab/simulink) to convert an octetstring to a short array of doubles?

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, simulink

I want convert an octetstring to a short array of doubles. The challenge is to compress more then two characters to a double value. One character is easy (just use the value of the character and convert it to a double). So an 'a' can be converted to '97.0' . Two characters can also be simple. 'ab' can be converted to '97.98'. But how two convert three characters to a double? Please take into account rounding in matlab.

The reason why I want to do this is that all data needs to be sent to another product which only accepts doubles.

Answer (score 0):

A double precision uses 8 bytes = 64 bits.
An ASCII character uses 1 bytes, but typical ASCIIencoding only uses the first 7 bits.

So, if we restrict ourselves to standard ASCII characters (in the 1 -- 127 range) we should be able to fit 9 characters into each double, since 7*9=63<64.

(We even have 1 bit to spare, we we could fit another character into each group of 7 doubles, but I'll leave that optimization out.  We're also leaving out any discussion of unicode, but this will work for many applications.)

There are a few Matlab commands to note:

1. typecast:  performs type conversions without modifying the underlying bits.  We'll use this to convert from `double` to/from `uint64`.
2. bitshift:  performs bit shifting on integer data types.  Can also saturate data, retaining only the lowest N bits.
3. bitor:  performs what the name implies .. bit level OR operation on unsigned integers.

Then, after a bit of experimentation, we can take some string:

```
strIn = 'How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?';
```

Then we can encode it to as `asDouble` array (via `asUint64`) using the following loop:

```
%Convert into doubles.  9 characters per double, 7 bits each.
asUint64 = zeros(1,ceil(length(strIn)/9),'uint64');
for ixChar = 1:length(strIn);
    ixUint64 = ceil(ixChar/9);  %Which uint64 are we writing to?
    ix7Group = mod(ixChar, 9);  %Which 7-bit piece are we writing to?

    %Create the encoded value
    curChar = strIn(ixChar);
    encoded = bitshift(uint64(curChar), ix7Group*7);

    %OR it into the current uint64
    asUint64(ixUint64) = bitor(asUint64(ixUint64), encoded);
end
asDouble = typecast(asUint64,'double');
```

And we can convert it back using a very similar loop

```
    %Convert back to str
strOut = char(zeros(1,length(asDouble)*9));

asUint64Out =  typecast(asDouble,'uint64');
for ixChar = 1:length(strOut);
    ixUint64 = ceil(ixChar/9);    %Which uint64 are we reading from?
    ix7Group = mod(ixChar, 9);    %Which 7-bit piece are we reading from?

    %Use bitshift to get only the desired bits
    encodedOut = bitshift(asUint64Out(ixUint64), -ix7Group*7, 7);

    %Cast to a char and store
    strOut(ixChar) = char(encodedOut);
end
%Strip unset characters
strOut(strOut==0)=[];
```

For what it's worth, the `asDouble` array is below, but it's pretty dangerous to think about it in decimal at this point:

```
>> asDouble'
     5.56929305361178e+196
     6.06383983172222e+259
     8.04093567858749e+177
     3.37314706618397e+259
     2.82456187483837e+266
     1.79945353109827e-150
      3.3731457960492e+259
     2.81037121975641e-306
```

As binary is a better way to think about it:

```
0110100011000111110101110110101000001110111110111110010000100000
0111010111011111100011010000011001001101111110111111101111101100
0110010011011111101111111011101000001100001010000011001001100011
0111010111010001100011010000011010111100011111010111010001100011
0111011101000001100001010000011001101101001010000011010111101111
0010000011010111100011111010111010001100011110010011011111100011
0111010111010001100011010000011001001101100111010111011111100011
0000000001111111100100110111111011111110111010000011010110000000
```